# Postgis add Geography to function()?

Tags: postgis, geometry, geography, length

i was wondering

im getting different results when using geography() on different positions within a query.

So, whats the most accurate way of forcing geography() over a functions with geometry columns?

example:

---

SELECT

polys.id,

sum(st_length(st_intersection(**geography**(lines.the_geom),**geography** polys.the_geom))))/1000  total_lengths

from 
schema.table1polys polys
schema.table2lines lines on ST_Intersects(geography(lines.the_geom),geography(polys.the_geom))

---

..or..

---

SELECT

polys.id,

sum(st_length(**geography**(st_intersection(lines.the_geom,polys.the_geom))))/1000  total_lengths

from 
schema.table1polys polys
schema.table2lines lines on ST_Intersects(geography(lines.the_geom),geography(polys.the_geom))

whats the most accurate? i have sort of 2 / 3 Km of difference between both querys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cast all geometry DB fields to geography and then do the calculations:

```
SELECT
polys.id,
sum(st_length(st_intersection(geography(lines.the_geom),geography(polys.the_geom))))/1000      total_lengths
from schema.table1polys polys schema.table2lines lines 
on ST_Intersects(geography(lines.the_geom),geography(polys.the_geom));
```